# Mock mounted hook Jest testing unit

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, babel-jest, vue-test-utils

I am doing some unit testing for components. However, in some components, I have something running on the `mounted` hook that is making my test fail.
I have managed to mock the methods that I do not need. However, I was wondering if there is a workaround mocking the `mounted` hook itself.

**@/components/attendeesList.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span> This is a test </span> 
  </div>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
methods: {
    testMethod: function() {
        // Whatever is in here I have managed to mock it
    }
},

mounted: {
    this.testMethod();
}
</script>
```

**Test.spec.js**

```
import { mount, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import test from '@/components/attendeesList.vue'

describe('mocks a method', () => {    
  test('is a Vue instance', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(attendeesList, {
    testMethod:jest.fn(),
  })
  expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy()
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, `vue-test-utils` does not support mocking lifecycle hooks, but you can [mock the method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53799803/6277151) called from the `mounted` hook. In your case, to mock `testMethod()`, use [`jest.spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname):

```js
const testMethod = jest.spyOn(HelloWorld.methods, 'testMethod')
const wrapper = shallowMount(HelloWorld)
expect(testMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith("hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

Vue test utils has a built in way to mock methods -

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(attendeesList,{
   testMethod:jest.fn()
})
```

the simplest way to solve your problem is to move the code in the mounted hook into a method, stub that using the code above and call it from your hook.

Comment: Wouldn't be too late to stub it?? Since the mounted hook runs before it gets the stub?

Comment: when using mocked methods via shallowMount the methods are overridden before the mounted hook is called.

Comment: Could you check my updated post, please? I get the exact same error, to be honest.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Replacing methods is no longer supported by vue-test-utils as of 2021