# how to mock 'mounted' method of VueJs component?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vuex, vue-test-utils

Thanks for you help in advance.

**How is the `mounted() method`  mocked for testing?**

The **Component** is like this:

```
export default {
    
    name: 'ShowToDo',
    ...
    mounted(){
        this.$store.dispatch('download_todo')
    },
    ...
}
```

Instead, the **Component-test** is:

```
  const localVue = createLocalVue()
        localVue.use(Vuex)
        wrapper = mount(ShowToDo, {
            store,
            localVue,
            mounted(){}
            }
        )
    })
```

It seems that `mounted(){}` is ignored, because the test try to execute `this.$store.dispatch('download_todo')` .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55746890/mock-mounted-hook-jest-testing-unit ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you can't mock Vue lifecycle hooks.

Source: [vue-test-utils issue #166](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/166)

What you can do though it mocking your store. Instead of using your real store, you can provide one with a custom `download_todo` declared action.

So the `mounted` hook will be run and dispatch the `download_todo` action, but it will be a custom one :)

```js
import { state, mutations, getters, actions } from '../store'

const downloadActionMock = jest.fn()
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  getters,
  actions: {
    ...actions, // Use the real actions
    download_todo: downloadActionMock // Override some of them
  }
})

wrapper = mount(ShowToDo, {
    store,
    localVue,
  }
)

expect(downloadActionMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Comment: I have moved the `this.$store.dispatch('download_todo')` in the init function inside `methdos`, then I mocked this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assert that lifecycle hook was called but you can assert the `$store.dispatch` was called. I suggest you to not use real `Vuex store` at all. One of the best practices is to test the store separately mocking the `$store` object in components. With mock `$store` you can not just check that the action was dispatched but also check what arguments it was dispatched with:

```
const wrapper = mount(ShowToDo, {
   mocks: {
     $store: {
       dispatch: jest.fn()
     }
   },
})
expect(wrapper.vm.$store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('download_todo')
```