# How do I mock a method that gets fired by a vue directive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to call the `close()` method in my `Test` component, but it only gets fired when clicking outside the `div` that the directive is on. What should I do in my test to make sure that that method gets fired? I'm using the `v-click-outside` npm package in my component.

**Component**

```html
<script>
  import vClickOutside from 'v-click-outside';

  export default {
    name: 'Test',

    directives: {
      vClickOutside,
    },

    data: () => ({
      isOpen: false,
    }),
    methods: {
      close() {
        this.isOpen = false;
      },
  };
</script>

<template>
  <div
    v-click-outside="close"
    class="test-class"
  >
    <OtherComponent />
  </div>
</template>
```

**This is my test file.**

```js
const clickOutsidelDirective = jest.fn();

describe('Test.vue', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(Component, {
   directives: {
      clickOutside: clickOutsidelDirective,
    },
  });
   wrapper.find('.test-class').trigger('click');
   //not sure what i have to do to mock the close() function 

   //This doesn't get called
   expect(clickOutsidelDirective).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directive is not setup properly in your component:

```js
import vClickOutside from 'v-click-outside'

export default {
  directives: {
    // BEFORE: ❌ 
    vClickOutside,

    // AFTER: ✅
    clickOutside: vClickOutside.directive
  },
}
```

To verify that `close()` is called when you click outside the component:

1. [Mock the `close` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53799803/6277151) with `jest.spyOn`.
2. Create a `div` for the test component, and [attach](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#attachto) the mounted wrapper to it.
3. [`v-click-directive` adds its event listeners on the next macro-tick (using `setTimeout` with no timeout)](https://github.com/ndelvalle/v-click-outside/blob/3e2c631/src/v-click-outside.js#L99-L106), so the test also needs to wait a macro-tick for the directive to initialize.
4. Trigger a `click` event on the wrapper, and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the result. Then, assert that `close()` was called.

The test should look like this:

```js
it('click directive', async () => {
  1️⃣
  const closeFn = jest.spyOn(HelloWorld.methods, 'close')

  2️⃣ 
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  document.body.appendChild(div)

  const wrapper = mount({
    template: `<div><HelloWorld /></div>`,
    components: {
      HelloWorld
    },
  }, { attachTo: div })

  try {
    3️⃣
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r))

    4️⃣
    await wrapper.trigger('click')
    expect(closeFn).toHaveBeenCalled() ✅

  } finally {
    wrapper.destroy()
  }
})
```

Comment: @FirzokNadeem This particular directive's implementation checks for clicks outside an element, so we wrap that element inside a `div` that can be clicked in the test. The target element needs to be attached to the `div` for the test to work.

Answer (score 0):

In your main component, the directive was imported explicitly. So, in your test, you do not need to define it again.
v-click-outside has a consequence, you should test it. It means, the close method should fire, mock it not the entire directive. Something like it:

EDIT:
Your definition to include [the directive is wrong](https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-click-outside):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div
        v-click-outside="close"
        class="test-class"
    >
      <h1>H1</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1 class="outside-class">Outside</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import clickOutside from 'v-click-outside';

export default {
  name: 'Test',

  directives: {
    clickOutside: clickOutside.directive,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    close() {
      this.isOpen = true;
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

By the new version of Vue-test-utils, method overriding is going to be deprecated, So, something like this should work:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(HelloWorld)
wrapper.find('.test-class').trigger('click')
expect(wrapper.vm.isOpen).toBeTruthy()
wrapper.find('.outside-class').trigger('click')
expect(wrapper.vm.isOpen).toBeFalsy()
```

But it does not. It's related to the internal v-click-outside implementation. I think there is a problem with the directive and shallowMount.

Comment: Seems like even doing it this way doesn't trigger the method/directive to being called

Comment: I've tested this template in the browser and everything went well. But in the unit test didn't work. It should be about the environment that the directive works in.